# Jquery subsequent tabs not loading ajax weather widget

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I'm building a site with a little (cookie-based) tabbed section that includes an AJAX weather widget. I know my problem is that the AJAX content is only loaded at the beginning and the rest of the tabs do not fire the event when clicked. I've found lots of solutions ranging from using load, cache, url hrefs, id hrefs, etc, but in every case I'm messing up the syntax when trying to implement. I'm not sure which solution is applicable to me (any/all of them?). It seems deceptively simple but I think I've been staring at this too long.

Here is my tabs html:

```
        <div id="profileTabList" class="tabs">
        <a href="#toronto">Toronto</a>
        <a href="#montreal">Montreal</a>
        <a href="#calgary">Calgary</a>
        <a href="#vancouver">Vancouver</a>
        </div>

        <div class="hr"></div>

        <div id="profileTabData" class="both">

            <div id="toronto" class="tab_content">
                <div class="left">
                <div class="ws-widget"><span class="ws-location">Toronto, Canada</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                <div class="ws-widget"><span class="ws-location">Moscow, Russia</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="montreal" class="tab_content">
                <div class="left">
                <div class="ws-widget"><span class="ws-location">Montreal, Canada</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                <div id="cbc-montreal"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="calgary" class="tab_content">
                <div class="left">
                <div class="ws-widget"><span class="ws-location">Calgary, Canada</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                <div id="cbc-calgary"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="vancouver" class="tab_content">
                <div class="left">
                <div class="ws-widget"><span class="ws-location">Vancouver, Canada</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                <div id="cbc-bc"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I'm using cookie-based-jquery-tabs.js:

```
$(function(){

function HashTabs(){
    var Cookie = $.cookie("offices");
    var activeTab = '';
    var navIndex = '';
    $('.tab_content').hide();

    if(!Cookie){
        $(".tabs a:first").addClass("active").show();
        $(".tab_content:first").show();

    } else if (Cookie != "") {
        $('.tabs > a:eq('+ Cookie +')').addClass('active').next().show();
        activeTab = $('.tabs > a:eq('+ Cookie +')').attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(0);
    }

    $(".tabs > a").click(function() {
        $(".tabs a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        navIndex = $('.tabs > a').index(this);
        $.cookie("offices", navIndex);
        $('.tab_content').hide();
        activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(0);
        return false;
    });
}

$('#profileTabList').each(function(){
    return HashTabs();
});
```

});

Comment: Is this actually an ajax problem? I'm trying to rebuild all this using the tabs package from jquery.com instead and the left: -10000px trick.

Comment: I basically scrapped this and used the new jquery tab code and left index fix. That does seems to work.